# What is the relation between the sisters and the bugs in “The Little Sisters of Eluria”

Tags: short-stories, stephen-king, the-dark-tower

I'm currently reading Stephen King's short story  "The Little Sisters of Eluria"

What is the relation between sisters and bugs? We know about the sisters but what do bugs get in return by healing people? and Why did Jenna turn into those bugs in the morning ?

Comment: Thanx @K-H-W. But jenna definitely turn into the bugs because when Ronald pick up her remaining cloths then her bells rings and remaining bugs tried to form a latter C. It was strongly suggested at that point that sisters are made of bugs. I don't think sisters have any weakness against the sun because they visited hospital tent in daytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are the Doctors?** from The Dark Tower wikia page:

> The Cam Tam, also known as Doctor Bugs or Doctors of Eluria, are
>   insects about the size of a small honeybee and are used by the Little
>   Sisters of Eluria. Unlike the Grandfather Fleas they are healers that
>   feed off disease and fix broken bones; while they are healing they
>   sing music that is very entrancing. Because of this these little
>   creatures help the Little Sisters blend in as nurses.

http://darktower.wikia.com/wiki/Cam_Tam

So in short, the Doctors feed on disease and that is what they are getting in return. They eat the disease and the people are healed as a result.

**Why did Sister Jenna turn into the bugs?**

> She was damned by the Little Sisters and, as such, her body dissolved into Cam Tam.

http://darktower.wikia.com/wiki/Sister_Jenna

Comment: Thanx, but why did jenna turn into them ?

Comment: Added an answer to the second part of your question